# Error using averageifs in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA code is like this:

```
Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs( _
        Sheets("Data").Range("B:B"), _
        Sheets("Data").Range("B:B"), _
        ">=" & Sheets("Result").Range("A" & i), _
        Sheets("Data").Range("B:B"), _
        "<" & Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i), _
        Sheets("Data").Range("B:B"))
```

However, an error message showed "Unable to get the averageif property of the worksheetfunction class".

When I change the critiria value to be a constant, however, it can run correctly:

```
Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs( _
         Sheets("data").Range("b:b"), _
         Sheets("data").Range("b:b"), _
         ">=" & 0.06, _
         Sheets("data").Range("b:b"), _
         "<" & 0.07)
```

What's the problem here? And how can I correct it?

-I found the problem was that there is no value within the specified range. But when I tried to debug using the iferror(） function, it still shows the same error message.

Comment: The first call to `AverageIfs` is malformed, while the second is not. `AverageIfs` expects a range to average, then a range to check, then a criteria for that check, then a range, then a criteria... etc. The first time you try it, you go (Range, Criteria, Range, Criteria, Range) instead of (Range, Range, Criteria, Range, Criteria).

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I just corrected it. When corrected there is also the error message.

Comment: Still has the same issue in the first call. Not sure what's going wrong with the third call.

Comment: Third one works fine for me

Comment: ...as does the (corrected) first one

Comment: Works for me too, Tim. @CofeinnieBonda Are you positive the third call is giving the *exact same* error? `AverageIfs` can give errors when no items match your criteria, and it will even be the same error number (1004).

Comment: Thanks for both of your help. I think I find where the error happens. That's because there is no value within the range given.

Comment: @CofeinnieBonda regarding your edit: the function doesn't *return* an error, it *raises* an error. So `IfError` won't work. Consider either validating the data/criteria before calling `AverageIfs`, or adding an Error Handler (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling#t=201608242103393690837) to properly deal with the error when it comes up.

Comment: if you drop the `WorksheetFunction` and just use `Application.AverageIfs()` then you can check the return value for an error without raising a run-time error.

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes up when

- there is no data in any one of the referenced ranges
- none of the data in column B matches the criteria